# Can IDEA automatically add Android support library?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-support-library

Is it possible with IDEA 12 (like with Eclipse) to automatically add `Android support library` either on demand or on project creation (like in Eclipse)?

So far we had to go to `extras` directory in Android SDK and copy the library manually. I wonder if it had changed?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is missing right now, please [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Comment: do I "create issue"? as I do not have privileges to do so.

Comment: Anyone can create issues in IDEA project after login, either create a new account or login with some OpenID, like your Google Account.